# Web modular en PHP.. me actualiza toda la pagina ¿cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Tags: javascript, php, html5, canvas

tengo este codigo:

```
<?php include("FOLDER1/archivos/MENU.php"); ?>

<?PHP
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != "index") {
    if (file_exists("./FOLDER1/".$_GET['id'].".php")) {
        include ("./FOLDER1/".$_GET['id'].".php");
    } else {
        echo "La pagina que estas buscando no existe";
    }
} else {
    include ("FOLDER1/inicio.php");
}
} else {
include ("FOLDER1/inicio.php");
}
?>
<?php include("FOLDER1/archivos/footer.php"); ?>
```

explicare su uso. al cargarme en mi index las 3 partes, tengo que en MENU.php aparte de tener la botonera adicional mente enseguida tengo una animación (musica).. carga la pagina y muestra todo pero cuando clickeo alguna seccion del menu .. si me carga la hoja php pagina solicitada, pero la animacion (musica) vuelve a empezar.. se supone que solo debe de refrescarse lo seleccionado por el menu.. es por eso que digo que no solo se actualiza lo que pides, si no toda la pagina y donde lo detecto es en la musica que vuelve a empezar y se supone que en una pagina web modulada en PHP no deberia de suceder eso que es lo que viene a sustituir a iFrames.. espero haberme entendido.. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, es "modulada" pero de manera estructural, por el hecho de usar `include()` pero esto sucede del lado del servidor, no del lado del navegador. De hecho, cada vez que haces clic en un link y la url del navegador cambia, el navegador hace una petición `HTTP` al servidor (`request`), este resuelve la ruta y ubica el destino, si es un archivo PHP, lo interpreta (con todos sus `include`s, condicionales, etc) y lo convierte en un HTML plano que el navegador pueda entender y por ultimo lo envía al cliente (`response`).

Para el comportamiento que buscas quizá necesites usar *iframes* o alguna librería *frontend* que haga este trabajo del lado del navegador (modularizar vistas, interfaces reactivas, etc) como **Angularjs**, **Reactjs**, **Vuejs**, etc. hacerlo tu mismo mediante **ajax**.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: De nada, espero haber aclarado su duda

Comment: usare ajax. aun que no me gusta porque no se indexa en buscadores y a demas no tiene una URL o cadena amigable, si me ayuudo muchas gracias